# Can not rename a folder inside $_POST

Tags: php, post

I browsed many references in this site and found that this works successfully:

```
<?php 
//tes to rename a sub folder
$oldDir="test";
$newDir = "testing";

if (!is_dir(dirname($newDir))) {
    mkdir(dirname($newDir), 0777, true);
}

rename($oldDir,$newDir);
echo 'successfully renamed into';
?>
```

Now,I need to rename a category label (directory). But, It gave me error:
`"warning"."No such file or directory in ...."` when I have a category name inside $_POST, as in illustrated below:

*First*, **submit.php**

[image]

```
<?php
$displCat = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM labelz ORDER BY label_name");
$displCat->execute();
$dataCat = $displCat->fetchAll();
    foreach ($dataCat as $tampil_cat) {
    $idcat=$tampil_cat['id'];
    $cat=$tampil_cat['label_name'];
    ?>

<form action="u.php?id=<?php echo $idcat; ?>" method="post" name="frmupdatekat">
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow:auto;">
<h4>Edit Kategori: <?php echo $idcat.". ".$cat; ?></h4>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtOldKat" name="txtOldKat" value="<?php echo $cat; ?>" style="border:0px;"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUpdateKategori" name="txtUpdateKategori"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="cmdUpdateKategori" id="cmdUpdateKategori" class="btn btn-success" style="vertical-align:middle; height:27px; padding:4px; font:12px Arial;" value="Update Kategori"/>
<br />
<br />
</div>
</form>
//.......
?>
```

*Second*, **u.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    $txtOldKat=trim($_POST['txtOldKat']);
    $txtUpdateKategori=trim($_POST['txtUpdateKategori']);

rename($txtOldKat,$txtUpdateKategori);
echo "<script>alert('Haadeeeehhh, ini koq error muluuuuuuuuuuuu!');</script>";
exit(); // stop to see if errors here.

if (isset($_POST['cmdUpdateKategori'])){
    if (empty($_POST['txtUpdateKategori'])){
        echo "<script>alert('Admin, Anda belum mengganti nama Kategori!');</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=adminz/kategori.php?target=kategori'>";
        exit();
        }
    else{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM labelz WHERE id=:id";
        $sth = $mydb->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':id' => $id ));

//....... others code
?>
```

I then used previous scripts but not work even to use:

```
__DIR__
__dirname(__FILE__)
realpath()
```

etc.

I also check if the `$old_cat` exists and it really exists. 
Here's the screenshot from filezilla (and also check in cpanel).
[image]
Then try using `trim()` in post value.
I also read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php to see if I was wrong.

**It seems, it doesn't work inside** `$_POST`.
So, What should I do since I need it to do inside that `$_POST`.
*Otherwise*, you may have other solution to.

If you find this is duplicate question, pls let me know the link.
Thanks a lot for your advice/suggestion/solution.

Comment: Do some error checks in your code, make sure `$old_cat` exists prior to renaming, make sure `$new_cat` is in fact a valid file/folder name and doesn't already exist,  make sure `$old_cat` and `$new_cat` are actually set etc.

Comment: thanks for your response. the $old_cat exists. let me edit my question to upload the screenshot of it

Comment: Also, don't just use `$_POST['old_cat']`, use `trim($_POST['old_cat'])` to make sure there's no whitespace around.

Comment: I did it also with trim(), but it really not work,mate .. I have included the statement about trim() in my question

Comment: `$old_cat` in your form is called "phythonz", your folder is called "pythonz"

Comment: @JeanGkol `rename()` is require full absolute path or check within same directory. Is that same directory?

Comment: @IkoTikashi, I just got fault in writing in my question. In my source code, it is written match

Comment: Don't just type your code here, copy and paste it.

Comment: it's all in public_html folder and the file is inside the public_html too

Comment: ok, I'll copy all of them ... pls in a minute

Comment: Read my first comment, add error checks to your code. And once again, in your screenshot it's called `phytonz`, in your filezilla screenshot the folder is called `pythonz`. THAT'S WHY YOU NEED ERROR CHECKS! Add error checks.

Comment: I checked five times for the script and directory. Directory exists and typed correctly, but I found in my database in $old_cat it types differently.
@IkoTikashi, pls answer it for my stupid eyes .. It works now .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some error checks in your code, make sure `$old_cat` exists prior to renaming, make sure `$new_cat` is in fact a valid file/folder name and doesn't already exist, make sure `$old_cat` and `$new_cat` are actually set.

Comment: Seriously, add error checking/validation. Glad we could work this out. And in case I didn't mention it before: add error checks :)

Comment: I found different folder name in Database, I'm careless indeed :p .. next time I must be more accurately .. :D